# Keytool получение доступа

Tags: android, keytool

Пытаюсь сделать первой приложение по VK api http://interosite.ru/articles/rabota-s-api-vkontakte-v-android. Необходимо получить слепок сертификата. Однако при запуске keytool через командную строку пишет:
Отказано в доступе

Что нужно сделать что бы разблокировать доступ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В студии есть возможность увидеть отпечатки ключей в `Gradle console`. Для этого надо запустить специальную задачу - `singinReport`.

После этого в `Gradle console` будут выведены отпечатки всех ключей.

Вот скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо за оперативность. Конечно хотелось бы узнать, что же не так в системе.